# I want to show compilation error or force to above method to use annotation @cacheKey for parameter(userId)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-annotations, aspect

I have below annotation for method:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(Element.Method))
public @interface Memcacheable {
    int expiresAfterSeconds() default -1;
    String cacheKey();
    String cacheType() default "MemCache";
}
```

and I have below annotation for parameter:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(Element.Parameter))
public @interface CacheKey {
}
```

And I have below method with annotates @Memcacheable:

```
@Memcacheable(cacheKey = "abc")
    public static String getDefaultShopShareSettings( Integer userId) {
}
```

I want to show compilation error or force to above method to use annotation @cacheKey for parameter(userId)